# particular citation style in superscript mode

Tags: citing, cite-package

In a document, I am using the package `\usepackage[superscript]{cite}`. Therefore, normally this package gives citation as superscript. But, somewhere in the text, I want to write as " .......[1]", and for other citations, it will be in superscript. If anyone has any solution, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use the non-superscript citation in combination with a note, you could use `\cite[note]{key}`. If you just want the number, you could try with `[\citenum{key}]
`.

Comment: Thank you. It gives exactly what I want.